# Is it possible to change the name of an object type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop

For example:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date); // [object Date]
Object.prototype.toString.call(new Array); // [object Array]
Object.prototype.toString.call(new Object); // [object Object]
```

Now consider this:

```
var PhoneNumber = function(number) {
    this.number = number;
}
```

I can override the `toString()` method, but it doesn't *really* rename the object type. It just kinda fakes it:

```
PhoneNumber.prototype.toString = function() {
    return '[object PhoneNumber]';
}

new PhoneNumber().toString(); // [object PhoneNumber]
```

However, l33t h4x0rs know my `toString()` method is a lie and I'm a n00b:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(new PhoneNumber); // [object Object]
```

What I would like the result to be, regardless of the `toString()` method being overridden on the prototype:

```
 Object.prototype.toString.call(new PhoneNumber); // [object PhoneNumber]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ECMAScript 2015 spec defines a well-known `Symbol`, which can be used to control this behavior: [`Symbol.toStringTag`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-well-known-symbols).  Unfortunately [no browser currently support it](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-well-known_symbols_Symbol.toStringTag).

Once it is supported, you will be able to use it like this:

```
PhoneNumber.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = 'PhoneNumber';
```

Which will produce your expected behavior:

```
new PhoneNumber().toString(); // [object PhoneNumber]
Object.prototype.toString.call(new PhoneNumber); // [object PhoneNumber]
```

Comment: As of [V8 release 4.9](http://v8project.blogspot.hr/2016/01/v8-release-49.html) this feature is available, so it should trickle down into Node and Chrome sometime this year.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But let me explain the problem first: you are not using the `.toString()` of your very class, but the `toString()` of `Object` wich has it's own definition and does not return the `toString()` of your object.

I have two solutions for you*: (Both tested in Edge, Chrome, Firefox, IE9-11)

**Solution A**

```js
Object.prototype.toString = (function(f) {
  return function() {
    return (this.toString === Object.prototype.toString
            || /\{\s*\[native code\]\s*\}/.test(this.toString.toString())
           ) ? f.call(this) : this.toString()
  }
})(Object.prototype.toString) // or just {}.toString


var PhoneNumber = function(number) {
  this.number = number;
}

PhoneNumber.prototype.toString = function() {
  return '[object PhoneNumber]';
}

document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(new PhoneNumber))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(Function()))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(Array()))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(window))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(1))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(null))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(""))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(document))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(document.createElement("div")))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(Object()))
document.writeln(({}).toString()) // check
```

**Solution B**

```js
Object.prototype.toString = (function(f) {
  return function() {
    return (typeof this._toString ===  'undefined') ? f.call(this) : this._toString()
  }
})(Object.prototype.toString)


var PhoneNumber = function(number) {
  this.number = number;
}

PhoneNumber.prototype._toString = function() {
  return '[object PhoneNumber]';
}

document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(new PhoneNumber))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(Function()))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(Array()))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(window))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(1))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(null))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(""))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(document))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(document.createElement("div")))
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(Object()))
document.writeln(({}).toString()) // check
```

- it only took me two hours to figure it out

Comment: That breaks toString on generic objects: `({}).toString()` will result in a call stack exceeded error.

Comment: @NoahFreitas Fixed that issue

Answer (score 0):

because Object.prototype.toString returns [[Class]] internal property of class, and the value of the [[Class]] internal property is defined by es5 specification for every kind of built-in object like Date, Regexp..
And in specification you can't find any way to access this property.
This property is using to set difference between built-in objects, so overriding toString can't change [[Class]] property and result always [object Object].
More Detailed how toString works http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2